# How to say "a man who has a good reputation"

Tags: expressions

Despite its hole-in-the-wall appearance, its bartender/owner, Gene Stewart, is ____.

In that blank, I want something like "a man of mild reputation". I entertained the thought of using "the talk of the town" but I think it is too strong.

Comment: "reputable" seems sufficient

Comment: Gene Stewart is ***well-respected***.

Comment: a man of good repute.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few ways you could say this:

- "Gene Stewart is quite a respectable man."
- "Gene Stewart is well respected around town."
- "Gene Stewart is a man everyone thinks well of."
- "Gene Stewart is a man with a solid reputation."

If you are taking of solidity of character you could say,

"Gene Stewart is a man worth his salt."